# Django Rest Framework - How to set the current_user when POST

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have just followed a small tutorial using DRF, but I can't figure how to like my model to his user when POSTing a new object

this is my model :

```
# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):
  # project title
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
  # subtitle
  subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

  #######

  user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and so my `serializer`

```
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ("id", "title", "subtitle", "user_id")
```

so, now in the `view` I have access to the current_user with this : 
`request.user`

```
class ListProjectsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]

    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Project.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

[...]

    def create(self, request, pk = None):
      return super(ListProjectsView, self).create(request, pk = None)
```

I suppose there is a way to passe the  `request.user` is the create in order to allow my Project.user_id to be filled ?

Whatever I'm doing, I can't manage to set the user, and i get the 
`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint` error

Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to override with following method. Everytime PUT/PATCH/CREATE operation is performed following method is called. This is the good way to pass the current user.

```
   def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user = self.request.user)
```

Comment: thank you a lot! this is exactly what I was searching :)

Comment: i'm using the same approach in my serializer, but still gets me that the user is required, im sending the user in perform create like this : serializer.save(
            user_id=user_id,
            channel=channel.id
        )
i try to even print the user to see if the view is entering the perform create but it does not enter, its like is validating the fiels prior to perform create and don't pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Project(models.Model):
  # project title
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
  # subtitle
  subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
  user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

okay so you have FK user but try to access it with the user_id = request.user.id

Just call

```
queryset = Project.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

queryset = Project.objects.filter **(user_id=request.user.id)**

if you want to match the id you should put  two __
like so `user__id = request.user.id` but I dont see any sence making it.

Comment: I already have the `request.user` working with the list, but my issue is that I dont know how to send the `request.user` to the model in order for it to save it in the `user_id` field

Comment: if you want to match the id you should put two __ like so `user__id = request.user.id` but I dont see any sence making it.